# JSON schema reference child key

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

The below JSON object will be responsible for rendering a select menu.

Using JSON Schema, is there anyway i can *dynamically* validate that the value of the `default` key (in this case "sm") matches at least one of the properties inside the `options` object?

I have looked at the docs and am hoping that this is possible using a combination of `pattern` `refs` and `json pointers` but cannot find an example of this use case.

```json
{
"top": {
            "label": "Small",
            "default": "sm",
            "options": {
                "none": {
                    "label": "None"
                },
                "sm": {
                    "label": "Small"
                },
                "md": {
                    "label": "Medium"
                },
                "lg": {
                    "label": "Large"
                },
                "xl": {
                    "label": "XL"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, what you're asking is not possible.

- the [`pattern`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation#name-pattern) validation requires a regex pattern
- the [`enum`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation#name-enum) validation unfortunately requires an array of values

One possibility - if you really, really, need this - is to define a vendor extension (but then you'll need to implement it in your schema validator).

Answer (score 0):

The `default` keyword is an annotation keyword and is not used for any type of validation purposes. JSON Schema doesn't support validation of keywords within a schema.

Comment: He didn't mean the json-schema `default` keyword he just has a field called "default" (you can see that in the example json he provided - which isn't the schema).

What he's asking for is a schema for **validating a field based on the values of another field**.